# Odd behavior in XQuery comments

Tags: xquery, sedna

I have a set of XQuery transformations that I am running on files stored in a Sedna database. They all have roughly the following format:

```
declare namespace ns0 = "http://www.someuri.com/foo.xsd";
declare namespace ns1 = "http://www.someuri.com/bar.xsd";

(:Declare a few functions like the following:)
declare function local:to-xs-boolean(
    $string as xs:string?
)
as xs:boolean? {
    if (fn:upper-case($string) = 'Y') then
        xs:boolean('true')
    else
        if (fn:upper-case($string) = 'N') then
            xs:boolean('false')
        (:if it isn't Y or N then attempt a normal cast - this will fail if it
        it isn't any of 'true', 'false', 1, or 0 :)
        else
            if ($string != '') then
                xs:boolean($string)
            else
                ()
        (:endif:)
    (:endif:)
};

(:Omitted several other functions:)

(:Start the main program:)

(: { :)
for $formName in /ns0:formName
return
        <ns1:newFormName>
            {
                let $address := $formName/ns0:Address
                return
                    <NewAddress>{
                        (:Omitted code and elements unrelated to this question:)
                    }</NewAddress>
            }
            (:Omitted code and elements unrelated to this question:)
        </ns1:newFormName>
```

Now here is my question. You see that line right above the 'for' that reads '(: { :)'? It should be a comment, but for some reason it is crucial to the proper function of my query. If I delete it completely (or remove the '{' from inside the comment) I get

```
SEDNA Message: ERROR XPDY0002
It is a dynamic error if evaluation of an expression relies on some part of the dynamic context that has not been assigned a value.
```

If I uncomment it (so the line just reads '{') I get

```
SEDNA Message: ERROR XPST0003
It is a static error if an expression is not a valid instance of the grammar defined in A.1 EBNF.
Details: at (393:1), syntax error, unexpected {
         at (798:33), syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting "," or }
```

If I have it both uncommented and add a matching '}' to the end of the file I get

```
SEDNA Message: ERROR XPST0003
It is a static error if an expression is not a valid instance of the grammar defined in A.1 EBNF.
Details: at (393:1), syntax error, unexpected {
```

If I add other text to that comment (like '(:text foo bar baz() blah {:)') it will continue to work as long as I leave that '{' in there.

Has anybody ever seen this before or have any idea what might be causing it? It isn't really a crucial issue (I can just make sure I have '(:{:)' in all of my transformations), but it is really making me curious. So thanks for any help, or even just joining me in puzzlement.

Oh one other quick note - I don't know if it makes any difference, but I am running the query out of Java using Charles Foster's Sedna API (http://www.cfoster.net/sedna/)

---

---

**Edit:** Here is a different query that I just wrote which shows the same issue. This seems reproducable to me, but if it is syntax error related it could be just me reproducing the syntax error. I will leave the old one up as well so future viewers of this question aren't confused.

```
declare namespace ns0 = "http://www.someuri.com/InitialSchema.xsd";
declare namespace ns1 = "http://www.someuri.com/FinalSchema.xsd";

declare function local:to-address(
    $recipient as xs:string?,
    $line1 as xs:string?,
    $line2 as xs:string?,
    $line3 as xs:string?,
    $city as xs:string?,
    $provinceOrState as xs:string?,
    $country as xs:string?,
    $postalOrZIP as xs:string?
)
as element() {
    if (fn:upper-case($country) = 'CA' or fn:upper-case($country) = 'US') then
        if (fn:upper-case($country) = 'CA') then
            <CanadianAddress>
                <City>{ $city }</City>
                <Country>{ $country }</Country>
                <PostalCode>{ $postalOrZIP }</PostalCode>
                <Province>{ $provinceOrState }</Province>
                <Recipient>{ fn:normalize-space($recipient) }</Recipient>
                <StreetAddress>{ $line1 }</StreetAddress>
                <StreetAddress>{ $line2 }</StreetAddress>
                <StreetAddress>{ $line3 }</StreetAddress>
                <StreetAddress/>
            </CanadianAddress>
        else
            <USAddress>
                <City>{ $city }</City>
                <Country>{ $country }</Country>
                <ZipCode>{ $postalOrZIP }</ZipCode>
                <State>{ $provinceOrState }</State>
                <Recipient>{ fn:normalize-space($recipient) }</Recipient>
                <StreetAddress>{ $line1 }</StreetAddress>
                <StreetAddress>{ $line2 }</StreetAddress>
                <StreetAddress>{ $line3 }</StreetAddress>
            </USAddress>        
        (:endif:)
    else
        if ($country != '') then        
            <InternationalAddress>
                <City>{ $city }</City>
                <Country>{ $country }</Country>
                <PostalCode>{ $postalOrZIP }</PostalCode>
                <Recipient>{ fn:normalize-space($recipient) }</Recipient>
                <StreetAddress>{ $line1 }</StreetAddress>
                <StreetAddress>{ $line2 }</StreetAddress>
                <StreetAddress>{ $line3 }</StreetAddress>
            </InternationalAddress>
        else
            <CanadianAddress>
                <City>{ $city }</City>
                <Country>{ $country }</Country>
                <PostalCode>{ $postalOrZIP }</PostalCode>
                <Province>{ $provinceOrState }</Province>
                <Recipient>{ fn:normalize-space($recipient) }</Recipient>
                <StreetAddress>{ $line1 }</StreetAddress>
                <StreetAddress>{ $line2 }</StreetAddress>
                <StreetAddress>{ $line3 }</StreetAddress>
                <StreetAddress/>
            </CanadianAddress>
        (:endif:)
    (:endif:)
};


(:{:)
for $addressForm1 in /ns0:AddressForm
let $token := xs:integer(data($addressForm1/ns0:submissionID))
return
        <ns1:NewAddressForm>
            <SubmissionID>{ data($addressForm1/ns0:submissionID) }</SubmissionID>
            {
                let $currentAddress := $addressForm1/ns0:currentAddress
                return
                    <NewAddress>{
                        local:to-address(
                            concat(
                                $addressForm1/ns0:fullName/ns0:firstName,
                                ' ',
                                substring(data($addressForm1/ns0:fullName/ns0:middleName), 1, 1),
                                ' ',
                                $addressForm1/ns0:fullName/ns0:lastName
                            ),
                            data($currentAddress/ns0:line1),
                            data($currentAddress/ns0:line2),
                            data($currentAddress/ns0:line3),
                            data($currentAddress/ns0:city),
                            data($currentAddress/ns0:provinceOrState),
                            data($currentAddress/ns0:country),
                            data($currentAddress/ns0:postalOrZipCode)
                        )
                    }</NewAddress>
            }
        </ns1:NewAddressForm>
```

And here is some sample data for the new query

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns0:AddressForm xmlns:ns0="http://www.someuri.com/InitialSchema.xsd">
    <ns0:submissionID>23774</ns0:submissionID>
    <ns0:fullName>
        <ns0:firstName>First</ns0:firstName>
        <ns0:middleName>Middle</ns0:middleName>
        <ns0:lastName>Last</ns0:lastName>
    </ns0:fullName>
    <ns0:currentAddress>
        <ns0:line1>Line 1</ns0:line1>
        <ns0:line2>Line 2</ns0:line2>
        <ns0:line3>Line 3</ns0:line3>
        <ns0:city>City</ns0:city>
        <ns0:provinceOrState>Province</ns0:provinceOrState>
        <ns0:postalOrZipCode>H0H 0H0</ns0:postalOrZipCode>
        <ns0:country>CA</ns0:country>
    </ns0:currentAddress>
</ns0:AddressForm>
```

If it is a syntax error that is behind this would someone be so kind as to point out to me which line it is on?

Comment: Its a very valid XQuery syntax. looks like your Java layer XQueryService xQuery Parser having some issue?

Comment: @kadalamittai Yeah, that may be what is happening here. I still find it very strange though. I could maybe understand the parser having troubles when there is a mismatched '{' in a comment, but having trouble when there isn't one is bizarre to me.

Comment: Seems like a bug in Saxon 9.3.04EE , too. I wonder what @Michael-Kay will say...

Comment: @Dimitre: Check my answer. I can't repro this with a proper syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the following line:

```
for $formName in /ns0:formName
```

In Sedna (remember Sedna is the database, not XQuery processor) there is no way to define default context item (see [XQuery 1.0, 2.1.2 Dynamic Context](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#eval_context)) prior the query execution. So it doesn't know how to evaluate `./ns0:formName` (which equivalent of simple `/ns0:formName`) - it just doesn't know what `.` means in this case.

You should load the document you want to process into the database and then access it with `doc()` function:

```
for $formName in doc('forms')/ns0:formName
```

As far as I know, you may also try [Charles Fosters's XQJ API](http://www.cfoster.net/sedna/xqj/) for Sedna (which should be anyway better than XML:DB API) which has support for defining context item.

BTW, if you have questions concerning Sedna's XML:DB or XQJ it's better to ask them directly in sedna-discussion list. There are very good chances that Charles will answer you.